# Create ML - Object Detection Training - Unexpected Error

Tags: ios, json, macos, object-detection, createml

I am trying to create an Object Detection model with CreateML.

But no matter what I do, every time I press "Train" I get the message "Unexpected Error". But without any further information.

Here is the annotations.json data:

```
[{"image":"bild.jpg","annotations":[{"label":"sneakers","coordinates":{"y":875,"x":473,"width":236,"height":602}}]},{"image":"bild2.jpg","annotations":[{"label":"sneakers","coordinates":{"y":883,"x":440,"width":245,"height":605}}]},{"image":"bild3.jpg","annotations":[{"label":"sneakers","coordinates":{"y":608,"x":362,"width":222,"height":522}}]},{"image":"bild4.jpg","annotations":[{"label":"sneakers","coordinates":{"y":777,"x":411,"width":254,"height":687}}]}]
```

And here screenshots from CreateML:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0JOa.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRzMp.png

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: complete guess, but maybe it needs more than one image to do the validation split?  you could try duplicating your image to see if that makes it work

Comment: I already had the same thought. I have also tried that. I even have downloaded an example project (images with annotation separated into test, train, valid). Nevertheless "unexpected error" comes again and again.

Comment: Hmmm...I think there's a way to view error logs, but I don't know what that is. What hardware are you on? Does xcode and its tools need to be installed too? Sometimes there's just a random popup you need to accept. Also, what happens if you try a different directory?

Answer (score -2):

I had GPU timeout and other issues. Just cancelling the error and clicking on Resume Training worked for me. The error might pop up for a few times, but after a while, the process will continue.